# Inserting a link in an ApexPages message

Tags: apex, error-messages, page-messages, pagemessages

I was wondering if there's a way to display a link in an `ApexPages.Message`. There's nothing mentioned in the documentation about it, so I simply did a :

```
ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.CONFIRM, '<a href="/">test</a>');
```

It seems like the special characters are transformed to their html entity, making the link unusable.

Any known workaround?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You may need to set escape parameter to false in your VF page.

```
<apex:pageMessages escape="false"/>
```

Comment: Super cool, never heard of that attribute. Working surprisingly well :D! Thanks @richard-n

Comment: Note that this means *any* HTML included in your ApexPages.Message objects will be rendered as HTML in the page, and if you have to undergo security review you may be asked to justify this choice.